# rails - rspec - why does this "validates_inclusion_of :role, :in => %w[one, two, three ] }" not work 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

I'm getting an error that this method does not exist but this seems fairly basic and I'm not sure why I'm getting the error?

```
it { should validate_presence_of :role } # This is OK.

 Failure/Error: 
it { should validate_inclusion_of :role, :in => %w[one two three ] }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `validate_inclusion_of' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fad7474f9b8>
```

For Code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :role
  validates_inclusion_of :role, :in => [one, two three]       ]
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### This is no longer relevant. ensure_inclusion_of is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See the next answer that uses validate_inclusion_of

I don't think there is a shoulda matcher for validates_inclusion_of like that. However, based on what's available in master on the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) project, I think you can do this:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:role).in_array([1,2,3]) }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work:  `it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:role).in_array(['admin', 'leader', 'user']) }` gave `NoMethodError: undefined method `in_array'`

Comment: What version of shoulda-matchers are you using? Looks like the in_array option wasn't added to master until about 3 months ago so you may need to upgrade if you need to use that option.

Comment: See next comment: The **is** a should matcher `validate_inclusion_of`.

Answer (score 12):

There **is** a shoulda matcher `validate_inclusion_of`.

`ensure_inclusion_of` [is deprecated](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/NEWS.md) and will be removed in the next major
release.

Are you sure your code is inside a `describe Model do` block?